# Small ms Sql query to get the max of an id with some criteria

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I want sql query to get the above result. The result is the maximum Id in TableA whose s_id in TableB has Stat=true i.e. 1.

The following does not do what I want:

```
select i.category_id,i.image_id,i.image_original,i.image_title,i.photographer 
from images i 
  inner join schedule s 
    on i.scheduleid=s.scheduleid 
    and s.status='live' 
where image_id=(select max(image_id) from images)
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? You have been around long enough to know that we don't "give teh codez" here.

Comment: i tried this: `select i.category_id,i.image_id,i.image_original,i.image_title,i.photographer from images i inner join schedule s on i.scheduleid=s.scheduleid and s.status='live' where image_id=(select max(image_id) from images)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [TOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) to retrieve only 1 row
Use [ORDER BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) to control the sorting, so you get the single row you want

```
SELECT TOP(1) a.id, a.[image], a.s_id, b.stat, b.[desc]
  FROM TableA a
  JOIN TableB b on a.s_id = b.s_id
 WHERE b.stat = 1
ORDER BY A.ID DESC
```

An [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19ef3/1/0) showing this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Nice explanation and link to SQLFiddle